# No module named 'psycopg2'

Tags: python, django, pip

I Installed psycopg2 using pip

```
C:\Users\username>python -m pip install psycopg2
```

Adjusted my settings to:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # also tried: django.db.backends.postgresql
    'NAME': 'name',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
   }
}
```

When I attempt to run the server:

> import psycopg2 as Database ImportError:
>
> No module named 'psycopg2'

So I ran this again and got:

> python -m pip install psycopg2 Requirement already satisfied (use
> --upgrade to upgrade): psycopg2 in ...

So what have I done wrong? I am new to Django

Comment: Is it possible that you are running your django app in a virtualenv or something similar? You are installing psycopg in the system site-packages

Comment: have you tried do `import psycopg2` in interactive console?

Comment: @m.antkowicz Yes I ran ` import psycopg2` and got  `>>>`

Comment: @rll - Possibly, I have a folder `C:/venvs/env1`. Do I need to install it it in the venvs, or env1?

Comment: if django is running on env1, in the command line activate that environment, then install psycopg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that while following the [installation tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/install/) you installed `virtualenv`, created some environment (like `env1`) and followed on to install django on that environment.

If so, than you are running django on that environment as well (otherwise it would not be installed). In order to install modules you need to first [activate the environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/) and then use `pip`.

Answer (score 11):

There is a possibility that you have two versions of python installed and `python2-pip` is aliased as `pip` while `python3-pip` is aliased as `pip3`.

Make sure you are using right version with `python` and `pip`.

So the command would be:

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

Comment: No module named pip3

Comment: This was the answer for me, I had been using easy_install instead of pip3 but that was just placing an egg file under python2.7.

Answer (score 5):

You can try

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Answer (score 4):

You may need to install the package from `whl` file, try the below command:

```
pip install psycopg2-2.6.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

You can download this package from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Requirement 'psycopg2-2.6.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
psycopg2-2.6.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: You can try the other files that you have in the link I above. Search by "psycopg2", you have 8 files to choose from.

Answer (score 3):

On mac-os pip install psycopg2-binary will fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Install below dependency before installing psycopg2

```
apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Now install:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Give the below command to generate DB for your Django config

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was unable to `import psycopg2` because I had created my virtualenv like this:

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 .venv
```

as soon as I change this to:

```
$ virtualenv .venv
```

Everything worked!